# Ms Excel - Find the value based on row and column reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

### Table Data

```
Date        Name    Login Hours
-----      -----    ----------
01/01/2018 - Peru   -   8:00 AM    
01/01/2018 - Jethro -   11:00 AM    
01/01/2018 - Ashraf  -  8:00 AM    
01/01/2018 - Edcel   -  9:00 AM    
02/01/2018 - Peru    -  9:00 AM    
02/01/2018 - Jethro  -  8:15 AM    
02/01/2018 - Ashraf  -  9:00 AM    
02/01/2018 - Edcel   -  2:00 PM    
03/01/2018 - Peru    -  8:15 AM
```

How can I get the data as in the below format,

1. Name as Rows
2. Date as Columns
3. Login Hours need to be placed against corresponding rows(""name"") and columns("Date").

   ```
              01/01/2018   02/01/2018   03/01/2018
   ```

   1. Peru
   2. Jethro
   3. Ashraf
   4. Edcel

Comment: Please [edit] your original question and add the code you already tried. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Transpose or pivot table come to mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a helper column to your data

1. `=trim(b2)&text(a2,"ddmmyyyy")`
2. Filldown the entire cells having data in the left.
3. In target range put the following formula
   `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM($I2)&TEXT(J$1,"DDMMYYYY"),CHOOSE({1,2},$D$2:$D$10,$C$2:$C$10),2,0),"")`

Your target table start from `I2` filled with names and `J1-AM1` with dates.